# ¿Como utilizo un merchant_order recien creado para que el usuario realice su pago?

Tags: mercadopago

estoy desarrollando una plataforma donde el cliente tendrá la posibilidad de pagar sus cuotas del plan que se le haya asignado. También es asignado un vendedor a este usuario, cada vendedor tiene su cuenta de Mercado Pago.
Hasta acá la idea es generar los pagos con el client_id y secret_id de cada vendedor, para que el cliente le pague directamente a este vendedor.

El problema surge en que no quiero generar un preference por cada usuario, ya que en la plataforma de MP voy a tener los items a pagar (ej: Plan 1, Plan 2, Plan 3), previamente generados.

Encontré que Merchant order sirve para enlazar estos preference por su id y también agregar referencias externas que necesito en la API cuando recibo la notificación de MercadoPago (IPN) para validar dicho pago.

El problema es que use: 
**$mp->post('/merchant_orders', $merchant_order_data);** 
para crear la referencia, pero esta no me devuelve un link de pago como lo hace el método create_preference().

**¿Como puedo usar merchant_order para enlazar las herramientas que tenga creada cada vendedor en su plataforma de MP?**

Mi codigo:

```
$merchant_order_data = array(...);

$merchant_order_info = $mp->get("/merchant_orders/" + merchant_order_data->id, false);

return response($merchant_order_info);
```

^ Esto retorna un json con la data.

GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve buscando y encontre dos cosas:

1. Los merchant_orders son nuevos y aun no estan totalmente documentados, crear un merchant_order no sirve porque al final tenes que enlazarlos a un preference_order y terminas en un camino redundante.
2. Los preference_order, en contra posición a mi pensamiento, no se replican en la plataforma, por lo cual se puede crear infinitos (botones de pagos volátiles) sin que el sistema los liste en el panel.

Por el motivo del caso 2, opte por crear los preferencen con el client_id y client_secret de cada cuenta de MP, en la base de datos guardo los datos que se generan, como el link y los montos de pago, ademas agrego datos de referencia externa (external_referer) y el link a donde quiero que haga el IPN, con el Id del vendedor, cuando el IPN impacta en ese link, se revisa el id del merchant o del payment con las credenciales del vendedor.

En la plataforma retorno el link de pago para que el cliente abone, luego aguardo al IPN para mostrar en pantalla el estado del pago.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando IPN's cuando creas una preferencia, recibes una notificación con el id del `merchant_order` asociado, con este id puedes consultar al endpoint */merchant_orders/:id* en cuya respuesta encontraras el `preference_id` que identifica a la preferencia inicial en la cual puedes consultar sobre el valor del `external_reference` que asignaste.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, porque me di cuenta que al generar preferences no se reflejaban en el panel como habia entendido, así que use este metodo, de igual modo tu respuesta no aplica a mi pregunta, porque la idea era entender como se usa un merchant_order creado, que alfinal termina necesitando un preference_order (se vuelve redundante el caso), por eso seguí por el camino inicial. GRACIAS igual!!!

Comment: Si, en realidad me parece que estás confundiendo conceptos los merchant order y los preferences tienen fines distintos, un preference es un conjunto de preferencias y características de un futuro pago, sirve como input inicial para iniciar un checkout un merchant order es el resultado de una preferencia creada por lo que únicamente puedes disponer de una url al checkout desde una preferencia

Comment: @ManuelManuBruña, si has encontrado una solución, por favor publícala y [marca tu propia respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) o [acepta la respuesta de otro usuario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) que haya solucionado tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: Mauricio ahi publique la solución, pero no me deja marcarla porque tengo pocos puntos.

Comment: @Joelibaceta lo entendi despues y por eso hice cambio de rumbo. De igual modo mi confusión se genero al encontrar la posibilidad de crear un merchant_order que se muestra en la documentación. Me parecio una buena opción pero no tiene una finalidad concreta. Luego encontre un comentario oficial aclarando que es una nueva opción que aun esta sin terminar de documentar. Gracias